# Google Mock: perform repeatedly actions in a specified order

Tags: c++, googlemock

Someone know how to program a google mock method to perform repeatedly a sequence of actions (one at a time), when we do not know in advance the number of calls to the method ?

```
something like :
EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo())
    .WillRepeatedly(.WillOnce(Return(2));
                    .WillOnce(Return(40));
                    .WillOnce(Return(7)));
```

Behaviour :

```
mock.foo(); // return 2
mock.foo(); // return 40
mock.foo(); // return 7

mock.foo(); // return 2
mock.foo(); // return 40
mock.foo(); // return 7

mock.foo(); // return 2
...
```

Thanks

Comment: The idea of unit testing is that you know in advance what is expected to happen in code under test. So your question is not valid question for UT.

Comment: In other words - you should write tests for case when this sequence happens once, other testcase when this sequence happens twice etc...

Answer (score 0):

I already mention in comments that this is not really good idea to write unit tests where you cannot have full control or knowledge about what is really happening there.

But anyway this is doable - e.g. you can invoke lambda that produces next result each time it is called:

```
auto valueGenerator = [idx=0, arr={2,40,7}] () mutable
{
    auto result = *std::next(std::begin(arr), idx);
    idx = (idx + 1) % arr.size();
    return result ;
};
EXPECT_CALL(....).WillRepeatedly(Invoke(valueGenerator));
```

If you needs to check this is not ended in the middle of sequence - do this way:

```
int idx = 0;
auto valueGenerator = [&idx, arr={2,40,7}] ()
{
    auto result = *std::next(std::begin(arr), idx);
    idx = (idx + 1) % arr.size();
    return result ;
};
EXPECT_CALL(....).WillRepeatedly(Invoke(valueGenerator));

/// Prossible in TearDown - or at the very end of test:
ASSERT_EQ(0, idx);
```